# How to transform an array of object as array into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays , something like this:

```
const firstarray = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']

const secondArray = [
       {
         id: 'prop1',
         values:['teste1', 'teste2', 'teste3']
       },
    {
         id: 'prop2',
         values:['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
       },
    {
         id: 'prop3',
         values:['anotherValue1', 'anotherValue2', 'anotherValue3']
       }
]
```

and I want to transform into a new array:

```
 array = [
{prop1: 'teste1', prop2: 'value1', prop3: 'anotherValue1' },
{prop1: 'teste2', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'anotherValue2' },
{prop1: 'teste3', prop2: 'value3', prop3: 'anotherValue3' }
]
```

So I tried:

```
const newArray = this.firstArray.map((key:string) => {
const obj = this.secondArray.find((element:any) => element.id ==key)
obj.values.map((value:any) => {key: value});
})
```

but I only got array of undefined.

Comment: You need `return` statements in your `.map()` callbacks.

Comment: Are the two arrays guaranteed to have the same order i.e. will `prop2` in `firstarray` always have the same index as the object with id `prop2` in `secondArray`?

Comment: Not really, but I can creat on the same order if it necessary

Comment: That second to last line should be `return obj.values.map((value:any) => ({[key]: value}));`. So a `return` to make the entire `{}` block produce a result, and `[key]` because otherwise you literally create an object `{"key": "something"}`, and a surrounding `()` because `{key: value}` is interpreted as a program block (`key:` being a label, and `value` being a statement which just doesn't do anything), while `({...})` tells JS that it's an object. Then of course it needs some further work, just this is how you could get *something*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the orders match and don't have things in `secondArray` that aren't in `firstArray` then you can remove the `filter`, `sort` and `firstArrayIndexMap`. (But then why would you need `firstArray` at all?) If you don't care abount the order of the keys in the resultant objects you can just remove the `sort` and `firstArrayIndexMap`.

The below creates an array such that at each index (matching the indexes of the object values array of the secondArray objects) of the array there's an object that collects the object id as key and value as value. Hmmm ... I think that's probably a terrible explanation, but my brain is letting me down at the moment.

```js
const firstArray = ['prop1', 'prop4', 'prop3'];

const secondArray = [
  { id: 'prop1', values:['teste1', 'teste2', 'teste3'] },
  { id: 'prop2', values:['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] },
  { id: 'prop3', values:['anotherValue1', 'anotherValue2', 'anotherValue3'] },
  { id: 'prop4', values:['fourthvalue1', 'fourthvalue2', 'fourthvalue3'] }
];

const firstArrayIndexMap = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(firstArray).map( ([index, val]) => [val, +index] )
);

const result = secondArray
  .filter((item) => firstArray.includes(item.id))
  .sort((a, b) => firstArrayIndexMap[a.id] - firstArrayIndexMap[b.id])
  .reduce((acc, item) => {
    for(const [index, value] of item.values.entries()) {
      acc[index] = { ...(acc[index] ?? {}), [item.id]: value };
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```